# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String in Struts' logic:equal tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I have an error when I want to acces my JSP page.

**My bean:**

```
public class BeChildren implements Serializable
{
...
 private String isFilledChildren;
....

    /**
     * @param isFilledChildrenthe isFilledChildrento set
     */
    public void setIsFilledChildren( String isFilledChildren)
    {
        this.isFilledChildren= isFilledChildren;
    }



    public String getIsFilledChildren( )
    {
        if ( getNom( ) != null )
        {
            return "true";
        } else
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
...
}
```

**Error:**

```
28/07/17-09:13:10,670 ERROR org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag - ServletException in '/pages/sub/dir/detail/body.jsp': javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Invalid argument looking up property: "bean.enfant.isFilledChildren" of bean: "sub/dir/detail"
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Invalid argument looking up property: "bean.enfant.isFilledChildren" of bean: "sub/dir/detail"

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Invalid argument looking up property: "bean.children.isFilledChildren" of bean: "sub/dir/detail"

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

**My JSP:**

https://pastebin.com/QmgtXBqA

```
...
<html:form action="/page/sub/dir/detail.do">
<html:hidden name="sub/dir/detail" property="modeCreation" styleId="modeCreation"/>
<html:hidden name="sub/dir/detail" property="bean.enfant.isFilledChildren"/>
....
<logic:equal name="sub/dir/detail" property="bean.enfant.isFilledChildren" value="true">
    .....
</logic:equal>
...
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var f = document.forms[0];

    function init(){    
        var isFilledChildren = document.forms[0].elements["bean.enfant.isFilledChildren"];
        ....
        if (isFilledChildren!=null && "true"==isFilledChildren.value){
        ...
        }
    }
....
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: @Mercer as you can understand we can check all this code! You could just paste the code which your programm says it has the problem! I don't think this it difficult to understand.

Comment: did you see the class cast exception? seems to be that your JSP expects the datatype boolean and not string

Comment: @MichaelMeyer i see that but i don't have a Boolean datatype

Comment: yes, that's the point. Try to rename your variable isFilledChildren to filledChildren and your getter and setter to setFilledChidren and getFilledChildren

Comment: @MichaelMeyer always the same problem

Comment: you still get the Class Cast Exception?

Answer (score 0):

The property that is of String type should use the string value to avoid `ClassCastException`.

```
<logic:equal name="sub/dir/detail" property="bean.enfant.isFilledChildren" value="'true'">
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is ecause you pass boolean value to isFilledChildren property as parameter

```
<logic:equal name="sub/dir/detail" property="bean.enfant.isFilledChildren" value="true">
```

In your bean the property accepts String value

Comment: pass boolean value to isFilledChildren property as parameter? Why the property that has a boolean value should accept String or how to convert the boolean to string?

Comment: try using value="'true'" ?

Comment: Right, the string value should be in quotes.

Comment: Itry using `value="'true'"`but i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type for isFilledChildren property to String would resolve this.

If it does not, try with `<logic:match />` and `<logic:notMatch />` (if it's feasible in this use case). See below for logic:match sample code"

```
<logic:match name="UserForm" property="favouriteFood" value="Pizza">
```